# scp and file owner

Tags: files, scp, chown

What are the reasons that could make a change in a file ownership after `scp`'ing it from one server to another?

The file ownership changed from '*owner*' to '*apache*'.
I used `scp -p` .
The user '*owner*' exists on both servers and has the same UID.

Comment: Just tar the files you want to copy with -p, scp the tar, and untar on the destination with -p as well.

Answer (score 14):

From `man scp`:

```
-p      Preserves modification times, access times, and modes from the
        original file.
```

You can see the `-p` option does not preserve ownership.

If you want to preserve file ownership, you can use `rsync` with `-o` and `-g`, which will preserve owner and group. This requires you to run `rsync` as root.

Answer (score 8):

When you scp, the ownership comes from the user you use to scp to the other machine. For example:-

```
scp FILENAME USER@HOSTNAME:/PATH/TO/DESTINATION/
```

The ownership of FILENAME at the host HOSTNAME after scp will be USER as owner and primary group of USER as its group ownership.